# HandleNotificationOpened are not handled if app is closed before i open the notification

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, onesignal

HandleNotificationOpened is working perfectly if App is on the background or running but it's not fired if i open the notification when app is closed.

I've tried to persist the data from event with SecureStorage, because i'm not sure if the event run but in the wrong time or it doesn't run at all.

```
public App()
{
    OneSignal.Current.StartInit("onesignal-id").HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened).HandleNotificationReceived(HandleNotificationReceived).EndInit();
}


private async void HandleNotificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenedResult result)
{
    var data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;

    if (data != null)
    {
        data.TryGetValue("Title", out object Title);
        data.TryGetValue("Conteudo", out object Conteudo);
        data.TryGetValue("Link", out object RLink);
        string lastvar = (Title.ToString().GetHashCode() + Conteudo.ToString().GetHashCode() + RLink.ToString().GetHashCode()).ToString();

        if (!ChecarDB(lastvar))
        {
            InserirDB(Title.ToString(), Conteudo.ToString(), RLink.ToString());
        }

        await SecureStorage.SetAsync("UrlFromPush", RLink.ToString());
        var page = new MainPage();
        MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(page, "MudarURL");
    }
}
```

Expected result is the application properly handle the event, No error messages at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue using URI Scheme to access early init background data, replacing the `HandleNotificationOpened` method for `Intent?.Data?.EncodedQuery;` with custom formatting method, that's how i got the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

**This method will not be called when app is closed.**

Although I did not use **[OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk#section-sending-notifications)** to push notifications , according to the Android/iOS system notification processing mechanism, when the app is closed, when the remote notification is received, the click notification will restart the app, and the notification processing mechanism is processed by the system tray.

So the `HandleNotificationOpened` method will not be called.

Comment: Then how i handle the background data when app is closed?

Comment: @GuilhermeNimer Hi , it is impossible to handle remote notificaton when app is closed .

Comment: There's no way to get the background data passed by notification in app launch when app is closed?

Comment: @GuilhermeNimer I think it's impossible. Have a look at this .https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive