# Xamarin.forms One Signal PromptLocation method

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, onesignal

I'm having some troubles with location, i've followed one signal [document](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk#section--promptlocation-) but as you can see in the SS, location point still null
[image: onesignal example]

And here is some code (following the order, MainActivity.cs in .Android and App.cs in PCL)

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
     ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

     base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
     PullToRefreshLayoutRenderer.Init();
     OneSignal.Current.StartInit("onesignalID").EndInit();
     OneSignal.Current.PromptLocation();
     Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
     LoadApplication(new App());
     App.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
}

 public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

```
public App()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     var config = RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration;
     config.SchemaVersion = 1;
     OneSignal.Current.StartInit("onesignalID").InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.None).HandleNotificationReceived(HandleNotificationReceived).HandleNotificationOpened(HandleNotificationOpened).EndInit();
     OneSignal.Current.PromptLocation();
     MainPage = new MainPage();
}

protected override void OnStart()
{
     OneSignal.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();
     // Handle when your app starts
}
```

The location request is prompting in app init as expected but even if i allow location sharing, location point in onesignal still null

Comment: Hey Guilherme! The link for OneSignal you put up just takes people to stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yo @Saamer , i've fixed this, thanks for the warning

Comment: Sweet! Share your Answer below so other users can search it and use it! Or wait did you mean you just fixed the link not the problem?

Comment: @Saamer just the link, i'm still having the problem hahaha

Comment: There's a lot of different ways of doing this. Since you are using Xamarin Forms, follow this sample since the docs I see are specifically for Xamarin Native instead. https://github.com/trollicode/Trolli/blob/7d44dc4fcf638a104f50488cf091236c7d7d842a/OneSignalAPI/OneSignalAPI/OneSignalAPI/App.xaml.cs Do you have an override for OnRequestPermissionsResult?

Comment: @Saamer i've updated the ask with OnRequestPermissions

Comment: @Saamer Thank u for the github project, i didn't found the solution for this but maybe i've found the solution for this [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659354/handlenotificationopened-are-not-handled-if-app-is-closed-before-i-open-the-noti) using the interface to get additional data from app launch

Comment: Unfortunately the interface method didn't work haha, i'll keep trying to solve this

Comment: So, did it not work on iOS & Android? Did you try `OneSignal.SetLocationShared(true);`

Comment: @Saamer Yeah, i've tried OneSignal.SetLocationShared(true); but with no results :/,
about iOS i've not tested yet

Comment: And did you add these permissions in the AndroidManifest file? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`. If you try iOS as well, that will help us diagnose whether the issue is a Forms code issue or Platform specific implementation problem